# Expression evaluation mode in haskell for scripting

Tags: git, haskell, scripting

As noted multiple times elsewhere (eg. [1](http://donsbot.wordpress.com/2010/08/17/practical-haskell/),[2](http://mainisusuallyafunction.blogspot.com/2011/10/shqq-embedding-shell-commands-in.html),...) scripting in haskell can be quite powerful.
A quick way can also be the [ghc expression evaluation mode](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/modes.html#eval-mode). this is what I actually find myself using more and more (I really like this feature in ruby).
A little example task:
"Find out all the folders that contained git diffs between the HEAD and a specific revision"

```
git diff --stat 9e2b68 | ghc -e \
  "getContents >>= return.(Data.List.nub).map(fst.break('/'==).head.words).lines"
```

This looks a little clunky, probably because I don't really know the details of using `ghc -e`.
Given that all the interesting part is just the `nub.map(fst.break('/'==).head.words).lines` the actual expression seems a little wordy.

- How do I tell ghc about modules I need to use so I don't need to qualify them using the full name?
- Can I make ghc pick up some kind of a configuration file that contains modules I frequently use?

I'd really appreciate seeing some examples from other usecases that will help my improve the way I use haskell for those kinds of little scripts!

*Sidenote: Commandline-foo wizards will probably laugh at this but I feel much more comfortable using haskell then bash scripting so this is what I want to use.*

Comment: For String → String functions I find `interact` to be a little less clunky: `ghc -e "interact $ <String -> String func>"`.  This frequently ends up as `ghc -e "interact $ unlines . map (<String -> String func>) . lines"`.

Comment: As a fan of both git and Haskell, who is not much of a "commandline-foo wizard", a blog post where you list a bunch of your git-related Haskell scripts would definitely be of interest to me!

Comment: @MatrixFrog Not restricted to git but maybe still interesting to you: [Scripting with GHCs Evaluation Mode](http://blog.coldflake.com/post/12412650749/scripting-with-ghcs-evaluation-mode)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regarding modules: `ghc -e` uses your `~/.ghci` file, so in this case, you'd add `:m +Data.List` to it (`import Data.List(nub)` is also supported since GHC 7 or so).

Regarding packages: You can use `ghc-pkg hide somepackage` and `ghc-pkg expose somepackage` to define the default set of visible packages (packages are exposed by default though; maybe I misunderstand your question).

You might find [eddie](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/eddie) useful.

Comment: good call with the .ghci file! Didn't know `ghc -e` uses the same file.

Comment: regarding the packages: No, hiding and exposing was not what I meant.

Comment: about eddie: looks really nice...has even a cabal install option. Haven't quite figured out how to pipe text to it but I will investigate! by the way...FunctorSalad...very creative name :)

Answer (score 5):

Like FunctorSalad said, `ghc -e` loads the `~/.ghci`  so you can use it to add any boilerplate that you might use in your script. In your case you could add

```
let script f = getContents >>= return f
import Data.List
```

to you `~/.ghci` file and then run:

```
git diff ... | ghc -e "script.nub.map(fst.break(=='/').head.words).lines"
```

Comment: +1: I was wondering what `((==)/)` was supposed to mean in the question.

Comment: nice! that's really useful! thanks for the tip! allows for a much smoother integration...

Comment: `((==)'/')` is the same as `('/'==)`.

Comment: @augustss , that is true, I just copy-pasted what was in the question, I'll change it so that is just a tad bit more readable...

Comment: @augustss thanks for pointing that out...the pair of `'`s was of course missing. And your infix notation is shorter and more pleasing to the eyes!

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the standard configuration per the .ghci file (apart from your global ~/.ghci, you can have specialised .ghci files in some directories, which will then be read before that), you can also pass a Haskell source file as command line argument, `ghc -e "expression" path/to/Source.hs`. `expression` will then be evaluated in the context of `module Source`.

Comment: cool...didn't know about the option to have a special .ghci file in your current directory.